# How to add animation like Photos app

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to add animation beetwen Views like in photos app. I've download a sample code from: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ViewTransitions/Introduction/Intro.html

And i know there is an animations types:

```
UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone            ,
UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft    ,
UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight   ,
UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp          ,
UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown        ,
UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve   ,
UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromTop     ,
UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom  ,
```

but what if i want to add effect when i swipe from left/right my screen will enter just like in Photos App

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Photos app does not use multiple screens to display the photos, there is only one `ViewController`, which contains a `UIScrollView`. And in the scrollview, many `UIImageView`s are added (and the `pagination` property is set to `YES`) so that when the user swipe with its finger, it sees the different views appear with the photos.

[Here](http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/03/uiscrollview-paging/) you will find a tutorial on how to precisely achieved this effect

Answer (score 1):

This code is reuseable and comes with all the functionality you will need, used it in a previous project and was very good. Link: http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/fgallery

Comment: I use this. this is very nice control